# You have uncommitted work pending - apex test with three callouts

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock

I am trying to create a test where there are three (mocked) callouts to a web service which then creates or updates records.

Within my test class if I try to run the callout/update code twice within the same transaction I get error - 'You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.'

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326129&type=1&mode=1

If I want to test the case of two callouts, I can get around this by making one callout outside the Test.startTest()/Test.stopTest() block and then one callout within it:

```
@isTest
public static void calloutAndUpdateTest(){
        //mock callout
        MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock MultiMock = new MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
        MultiMock.setStaticResource('https://mockwebservice/hello', 'staticResource1');
        Multimock.setStatusCode(200);
        Multimock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, Multimock);
        //make callout and update
        contact webServiceContact = webServiceClass.getContactFromWebServiceAndCreateOrUpdate('hello');
        //check contact is created        
        Integer contactCount = [SELECT count() FROM contact];
        System.assertEquals(1, contactCount);
        //Start test -
        Test.startTest();  
           ... Same as above - create 2nd contact
        Test.stopTest();
        Integer contactCount = [SELECT count() FROM contact];
        System.assertEquals(2, contactCount);
        // THIS WORKS
}
```

Is there any way I can add an additional callout/update into my test method? (I want to do this because I want to create two contacts, merge them, and then check that an update will update the contact correctly.

Comment: can you add code of `getContactFromWebServiceAndCreateOrUpdate`

Comment: You are not going to be able to in one transaction (which is the testmethod scope) callout - update - callout.  You need to decompose your implementation so you can unit test each piece in separate testmethods. Enterprise Patterns and mocked services can help a lot here